# Refresh JFrame? Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I don't know how to resolve this case:
I have a JFrame with JPanel on it. I added two JButtons to this JPanel.

Class MainFrame

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    public MainFrame(){
        this.setSize(100,100);
        MainPanel panel = new MainPanel();
        this.add(panel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and MainPanel with two buttons

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    JButton button, example;

    public MainPanel(){
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JButton button = new JButton("New");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        JButton example = new JButton("example");
        this.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(example, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource().equals(button)){
            example.setEnabled(false);
            example.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        }
    }
}
```

and start class Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
    }
}
```

What should I do to change background color second button?

Answer (score 1):

You have your button variables defined twice, once as an instance variable and once as a local variable.

Get rid of the local variable:

```
//JButton example = new JButton("example");
example = new JButton("example");
```

Now your ActionListener code can reference the instance variable.

Answer (score -1):

In your example:

```
JButton button, example;    // <-- Here, you create your two (protected) variables

public MainPanel(){
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JButton button = new JButton("New");    // <-- And here, you create a local variable
    button.addActionListener(this);
    JButton example = new JButton("example");    // <-- Here, another local variable
    this.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(example, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource().equals(button)){
        example.setEnabled(false);
        example.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    }
}
```

Comment: (1-) This points out what the problem might be but doesn't provide an answer on how to fix it. In any case the problem/solution was already given earlier. No need to clutter the forum with attempted duplicate answers.

Comment: I have answer to this question maybe 2 minutes after the other answer so i didn't know than there were another answer